# Future delivery

Tags: word-request, adjectives

Is there any adjective to describe the situation where the commodities to be delivered in the future.For example Is there any way to make the sentence below simpler by using any adjcetive instead of “ that will be delivered in the future” like; “a future commodity or a commodity for future deliver?

> I bought a commodity that will be delivered in the future

Comment: Do you mean paying now for some commodity that isn't available yet, but will be delivered when it is available? Or do you mean committing yourself to purchasing something like stocks at a specific future time, regardless of the price?

Comment: I mean paying now for some commodity that isn't available yet, but will be delivered when it is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pre-order**

To pre-order something means to pay for it in advance of it being available on the market. This guarantees that it will ship when it becomes available, and often includes some bonus items.

For example,

> I pre-ordered Fallout 76 to get the free backpack.